# PHP return array of database object to AJAX Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

So when i try to return an array of database object to my AJAX and parse it, it becomes in an array of chars. I mean my `json_encode` result is `[{'id':38, 'first_name':jana}]` and when try to parse it to array in the ajax what is happen is and array of chars - `['[', '{', ''']` etc. This is my ajax:

```
function searchInput() {
    var $content = $('.jobboard-quick-search-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url : '/admin/site/search',
        method : "GET",
        data : $content,
        success : function ( data ) {
            var arr = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(arr);
        }
    });
}
```

and my action:

```
public function actionSearch()
    {
        $lang = \frontend\models\Lang::getCurrent();
        $pageSize = 100;

        if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
        {
            $search = \Yii::$app->request->get('search-label');
            $town = \Yii::$app->request->get('towns-list');

            $startsWith = '%'.$search;
            $between = '%'.$search.'%';
            $endsWith = $search.'%';

            $joinDoctors = "SELECT `doctor`.`id`, `doctorLang`.`first_name`, `doctorLang`.`second_name`, `doctorLang`.`city`, `doctorLang`.`hospital_name`
                            FROM `doctor` LEFT JOIN `doctorLang` ON `doctor`.`id`=`doctorLang`.`doc_id`
                            WHERE `doctorLang`.`city`='$town' 
                            AND `doctorLang`.`language`='$lang->url' 
                            AND `doctor`.`active`=1
                            AND (`doctorLang`.`first_name` LIKE '$startsWith'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`first_name` LIKE '$between'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`first_name` LIKE '$endsWith'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`second_name` LIKE '$startsWith'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`second_name` LIKE '$between'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`second_name` LIKE '$endsWith'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`third_name` LIKE '$startsWith'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`third_name` LIKE '$between'
                            OR `doctorLang`.`third_name` LIKE '$endsWith')";

            $doctor =  \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($joinDoctors)->queryAll();


            $joinHospitals = "SELECT `hospital`.`id`, `hospitalLang`.`title`, `hospitalLang`.`address`, `hospitalLang`.`description`
                            FROM `hospital` LEFT JOIN `hospitalLang` ON `hospital`.`id`=`hospitalLang`.`hospital_id`
                            WHERE `hospitalLang`.`city`='$town' 
                            AND `hospitalLang`.`language`='$lang->url' 
                            AND `hospital`.`active`=1
                            AND (`hospitalLang`.`title` LIKE '$startsWith'
                            OR `hospitalLang`.`title` LIKE '$between'
                            OR `hospitalLang`.`title` LIKE '$endsWith')";


            return json_encode($doctor);

        }

    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should cast the value you need  as number

Comment: First of all - your code is open to SQL injection, use [Yii 2 query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html). Second - have you tried to remove `JSON.parse(data);` and output `data` directly? There's a big chance it's already JSON parsed.

Comment: Yes i have but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add in ajax:

```
dataType: 'json'


$.ajax({
            url:<code>,
            type: <code>,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:<code>
        })
```

Next try use restController

```
class DataController extends yii\rest\Controller
{
    public function actionSearch()
    {
        [.....]
        return \Yii::$app->db->createCommand($joinDoctors)->queryAll();
    }
}
```